# jsTree with checkbox and state plugin forget checked checkboxes

Tags: jstree

Using jsTree with checkbox and state plugin, each time I check some checkboxes and reload page they are still checked. How is possible to use state plugin with checkboxes, but "forget" checkbox state (leaving opened and selected node state as is).

```
plugins : ["grid", "state", "dnd", "types", "checkbox"],
```

I created some example [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dhskgky0/7/).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `state.filter` option:

```
filter : function (state) {
    delete state.checkbox;
    return state;
}
```

Here is the updated fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/dhskgky0/8/